# Flutter Desktop Application error MSB4100

Tags: flutter

I was trying to do is to build Windows desktop apps with Flutter. I just followed all the steps of installation that were written in the documentation of Flutter. I just created a simple boilerplate with the command flutter create learningflutter on my Windows 11 machine. Then I just run the flutter run -d windows command inside the directory (learningflutter), then ended up with this error:

**C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(489,26): error MSB4100: Expected "$([System.String]::new('%(Link.AdditionalDependencies)').Contains('atls.lib'))" to evaluate to a boolean instead of "$([System.String]::new('..\flutter\Debug\flutter_wrapper_app.lib;D:\My File\Documents\Much Aris'z\Work\Salesman Tracking\Code\salesman_tracking_applications\windows\flutter\ephemeral\flutter_windows.dll.lib;kernel32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;winspool.lib;shell32.lib;ole32.lib;oleaut32.lib;uuid.lib;comdlg32.lib;advapi32.lib').Contains('atls.lib'))", in condition "'$(ATL_KeyFile)' != '' and ('$(ConfigurationType)' == 'Application' or '$(ConfigurationType)' == 'DynamicLibrary') [D:\My File\Documents\Much Aris'z\Work\Salesman Tracking\Code\salesman_tracking_applications\build\windows\runner\salesman_tracking_applications.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(489,26): error MSB4100:                          and %(Link.AdditionalDependencies) != '' and  $([System.String]::new('%(Link.AdditionalDependencies)').Contains('atls.lib'))". [D:\My File\Documents\Much Aris'z\Work\Salesman Tracking\Code\salesman_tracking_applications\build\windows\runner\salesman_tracking_applications.vcxproj]**

Answer (score 0):

Hope you found an answer, but for anyone having the same problem, I just had it and it will happen if a folder in your project's path contains a quote. If you remove that quote and delete the build folder, it will reevaluate correctly and work as expected :)